# warning: passing argument 1 from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct, kernel

I'm doing some work with structs for a kernel module on Linux with c, and I can't seem to get a pointer to an object within a struct. My code is as follows:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

struct list_head *list;

/* performs a depth-first traversal of the list of tasks in the system. */
void print_task_info(struct task_struct *task) {

    for_each_process(task){

        printk("%s, %d, %d \n", task->comm, (int)task->state, task->pid);
    }
    list_for_each(list, &init_task.children){
        print_task_info(&task->children);
        task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
    }
}
```

The problem arises when  I make a recursive call to print_task_info(). I've tried adding a lot of different things, using the unary *, having no symbols, casting, none of it worked for me. Do you have any advice? I searched but I can't find any resources about this in any C language documentation about structs, how to make this a pointer, so I came here when I ran out of other options.

Comment: The chances are you need to omit the `&`; I'm guessing that `children` is a `struct task_struct *`.  If your compiler isn't telling you about the types, it would be a good idea to upgrade to a version of GCC that does tell you the types involved in a type mismatch.  It is a lot easier to understand what's going wrong when the compiler tells you explicitly about the types.

Comment: Ok, somehow I missed the second... 3/4 of your comment. I could only see your suggestion of removing the &, sorry about that.

Comment: OK; then you need to find out what type it is because you aren't going to be able to call the function recursively until you know what type `task->children` has.  You can look through the headers as well as I can — better since they're on your machine and may not be on mine.

Comment: @RobertCrawford can you explain this? `task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);`

Comment: @iharob this code was provided for me, and doesn't produce any errors, so I've left it alone. I presumed it was for subsequent iterations, but come to think of it... I'll try rearranging a few things and seeing if something works...

Comment: @iharob OK, OK, I found the problem. Apparently, that makes task a struct task_struct*, which allows me to recursively call the function again. Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake!